# Why is touchmove never ending in chrome for Android?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, touchmove

I have this code working in chrome desktop. I tested it using simulate touch and it works as expected. My surprise came when I tried to watch it on my tablet, using chrome for Android. This is complex but it is supposed to create a touch pad for controling the camera. It captures the start and if you move the finger 50 pixels to any side you start moving towards it. When you stop touching the pad should desapear and the movement should stop. Meanwhile, when I do this on my tablet, it doesn't move at all, and what is more, when I stop touching, if I have moved the finger, the pad never hides... I don't know if this is problem of my code or if it is of the browser itself.

EDIT: I tried firefox for android and it works. It must be something about chrome... I think it is related with e.preventDefault();

The code is the following:

```
    function handleStart (event) {
        mando.tactil=true;
        mando.tactilX=event.changedTouches[0].clientX;
        mando.tactilY=event.changedTouches[0].clientY;
    }
    function handleEnd (event) {
        mando.tactil=false;
        animTactil();

        mando.tactilX=0;
        mando.tactilY=0;
        mando.tactilMoveX=0;
        mando.tactilMoveY=0;
    }
    function handleMove (event) {

        mando.tactilMoveX=event.changedTouches[0].clientX;
        mando.tactilMoveY=event.changedTouches[0].clientY;
        animTactil();
    }
    function animTactil () {
            if(mando.tactilX>w/3){
                //TACTIL DERECHA
                if(mando.tactilMoveX>mando.tactilX+tamanoDedo && mando.tactil){
                    mando.de=true;
                }else if(mando.tactilMoveX>mando.tactilX+tamanoDedo  && !mando.tactil && mando.de || mando.de && mando.tactil){
                    mando.de=false; mando.inerciaDE = vel;
                }else{mando.de=false;}

                //TACTIL IZQUIERDA
                if(mando.tactilMoveX<mando.tactilX-tamanoDedo && mando.tactil){
                    mando.iz=true;
                }else if(mando.tactilMoveX<mando.tactilX-tamanoDedo  && !mando.tactil && mando.iz || mando.iz && mando.tactil){
                    mando.iz=false; mando.inerciaIZ = vel;
                }else{mando.iz=false;}

                //TACTIL ARRIBA
                if(mando.tactilMoveY<mando.tactilY-tamanoDedo && mando.tactil){
                    mando.ar=true;
                }else if(mando.tactilMoveY<mando.tactilY-tamanoDedo  && !mando.tactil && mando.ar || mando.ar && mando.tactil){
                    mando.ar=false; mando.inerciaAR = vel;
                }else{mando.ar=false;}

                //TACTIL ABAJO
                if(mando.tactilMoveY>mando.tactilY+tamanoDedo && mando.tactil){
                    mando.ab=true;
                }else if(mando.tactilMoveY>mando.tactilY+tamanoDedo  && !mando.tactil && mando.ab || mando.ab && mando.tactil){
                    mando.ab=false; mando.inerciaAB = vel;
                }else{mando.ab=false;}
    }
}

if(tactil){
    canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("touchend", handleEnd, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", handleMove, false);
}
```

Comment: There's relevant context code missing: how do you attach the handlers? Further: does any error happen? You might try [remote debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) your Code from Desktop Chrome (Tablet connected via USB).

Comment: I've also realised that when I do weird stuff, like touching crazily, it starts moving, instead of doing nothing.

Comment: I'm trying other touch browsers